# Drupal Deployment to Dev & Prod and Git Code Repository Setup

Tags: version-control, deployment, staging

I have a dev and a prod server with 4 other developers. What is the most efficient way of setting up a development code push environment without the need to have to get too involved in the process? I know the term these days is called CI (continuous integration). But the thing is that it can involve many moving parts during deployment I've read some setups have automated testing in the process. I don't believe I would need that as that's an extra system to manage.

My sites are just mainly information sites and its mainly used internally which is less than 1000 hits a day.

What is the simplest way some people approach this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI (continous integration) can contain many moving parts during deployment and code pushes. But instead of using all of it, which isn't necessary for every site, I've come up with the following setup:

- 2 environments: Dev and Prod domains
- Code revisions gets stored in the git servers
- 2 git branches: dev and master, the master branch is the prod server code.
- Each developer will have their own local servers for testing and coding on their laptops.
- Each developer checks out the dev branch.
- Master (prod) branch should only be touched when dev is tested. Then, merge dev into master.
- Once a push to the Dev branch is detected, script on server will auto 'git pull' to get new changes.
- Once a merge with dev + master, script on server will auto 'git pull' to get new changes into prod.
- Drupal files content will be managed by the "Stage File Proxy" module without the need to download all files.
- Database will be synced by downloading a copy from the dev server with "drush sql-dump"